# how to add ccMenu just after the admob view is loaded

Tags: ios6, cocos2d-iphone, admob

I am using cocos2d-iphone for this game. In a Layer, I added the admob as pop-up ad. I want to add a ccMenu together with the admob view, so that the admob view could be removed after the ccmenuItem is clicked. But how can I know when the admob view is loaded?

I tried below methods,but the menu item and admob view can not be loaded the same time:

```
UIViewController *controller=[CCDirector sharedDirector];
CGSize size=[[CCDirector sharedDirector]winSize];
controller.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
_bannerViewTable=[[GADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, GAD_SIZE_300x250.width, GAD_SIZE_300x250.height)];

_bannerViewTable.adUnitID=@"xxxxxxxxxx";
[_bannerViewTable setRootViewController:controller];
[_bannerViewTable loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];

if (_bannerViewTable!=nil) {
    CCLOG(@" _bannerViewTable!=nil");
    CCCallFunc *loadView=[CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(loadAdTable)];
    CCCallFunc *addRemove=[CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(addMenuToLayer)];
    CCSequence *seq=[CCSequence actionOne:loadView two:addRemove];
    [self runAction:seq];
}else{
    CCLOG(@" _bannerViewTable=nil");
}

-(void)loadAdTable
{
  UIViewController *controller=[CCDirector sharedDirector];
  [controller.view addSubview:_bannerViewTable];
 }

-(void)addMenuToLayer
{
  CCSprite *removeBtn=[CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"minus1.png"];
  CCMenuItemSprite *removeImg=[CCMenuItemSprite itemWithNormalSprite:removeBtn  selectedSprite:nil target:self selector:@selector(removeAdTable)];
  removeImg.position=ccp(343, 282);
  menu=[CCMenu menuWithItems:removeImg, nil];
  menu.anchorPoint=CGPointZero;
  menu.position=CGPointZero;
  [self addChild:menu z:1];
}
```

How can I add a remove ccMenuItem the same time as the admob view is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

you probably should implement the [GADBannerViewDelegate](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/intermediate) As it reports when an ad is received and when the ad will be shown.

If you implement it in your class you can trigger to remove the ccMenuItem.